# Add record to table, and edit records in 2 separate tables

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access

Hi there I'm making an access database, and I can't figure out how to do one particular thing.

I've got a form with two text boxes: MovieID and CustomerID. I also have three separate tables: MovieList, CustomerInfo and HireHistory. What I need is so that when I enter a MovieID and CustomerID into the given boxes then press my button HireButton, it edits that specific MovieID's LastHireDate to Today(), edits that specific CustomerID's LastHireDate to Today(), and then in my HireForm (which has the CustomerID's in the first row) it adds a new record below the CustomerID in the form of: `MovieID " on " Today()`

Also, I need to make it so that it checks that MovieID's genre and if it's R16 or R18, then it checks whether the customer is older than 16 or 18 today, and if not then it comes up with an error box. I know how to do the checking whether they are older than 16 or 18, but not the error box.

I know that's a lot of text, so I'll just write what's in my brain (how I see the code should be) so it will be easier to see what I want to do.

```
IF MovieID.Rating = 'R16' OR 'R18'
   THEN IF CustomerID.[Date(Year(DOB)+16,Month(DOB),(Day(DOB))] > Today()
           THEN DISPLAY Msgbox = "Sorry, too young"

           ELSE SET CustomerID.LastHireDate = Today() 
                SET MovieID.LastHireDate = Today()
                ADDRECORD in HireHistory for that CustomerID to (MovieID & " on " & Today())

   ELSE SET CustomerID.LastHireDate = Today() 
        SET MovieID.LastHireDate = Today()
        ADDRECORD in HireHistory for that CustomerID to (MovieID & " on " & Today())
```

Does that explain it a bit better? Thanks in advance for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

so here How I would do this. You first have to create a recordset for each of those table.

For the age I would use this function.  : http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/modules/examples/AgeCalculation.asp

```
customerBirth = yourCode to get the date

If MovieID.Rating = 'R16' OR 'R18' then

    If AgeYears(customerBirth) < 16 then 
        msgbox("Sorry, too young")
    else
        MyCustomerRecordSet("LastHireDate") = now
        MyMovieRecordSet("LastHireDate") = now

        MyHireRecorset.AddNew
            MyHireRecorset("I don't know what your trying to do here")
        MyHireRecorset.Update

    end if

Else
        MyCustomerRecordSet("LastHireDate") = now
        MyMovieRecordSet("LastHireDate") = now
        MyHireRecorset.AddNew
        MyHireRecorset("I don't know what your trying to do here")

End if
```

If you have any question just ask.

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply. How do I set the values within my text boxes to be used as MovieID and CustomerID? I tried: `HireMovieID As Integer` and `Set HireMovieID = MovieID`, but it doesn't work. I edited my question, that might help. :)

Comment: Are you saying you want your text box to reflect what is in the table?

Comment: Yes pretty much. I need it so that it uses my HireMovieID as a filter for my MovieID in my MovieList table, same with CustomerID. :)

Comment: You just have to add an existing field from the design view.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your comment. I don't want it so that the text box shows whats in the table, when it's in the form, but I want it so that when an ID is entered in the text box: 'HireCustomerID' (e.g. 0003) that number is used to check whether that customer (CustomerID = 0003) is over 16 or not.

Comment: Ok, I would do a Dlookup to find the date and then feed this date to the function above.